# What happens when you send transaction with higher nonce that conflicts with previous transaction balance?

Tags: transactions, pending-transactions

As an example:

> Current ETH balance: 10 ETH
>
> **TrxA**  nonce: 88, amount: 7 ETH
>
> **TrxB** nonce:89, amount: 5 ETH

From what i understand, as long as TrxA is still pending, TrxB can be created by increasing the nonce value. However, TrxA has to be confirmed first before TrxB can be processed.

If i'm right, does that mean that TrxB can be successfully submitted to pool but will be rejected once TrxA is confirmed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From what i understand, as long as TrxA is still pending, TrxB can be created by increasing the nonce value. However, TrxA has to be confirmed first before TrxB can be processed.

This is correct. TrxB can potentially float around in the memory pool until TrxA is mined, but then TrxB will be dropped if it's invalid.

Comment: TrxB might not be rejected immediately but keep around until the account has enough funds.